# How to make the css child class inherits the parent css class

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic4

I need to the child css class inherit the properties from their parent css class

```css
.avatar {
  min-width: 35px;
  max-width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  flex: 1 1 35px;

  &--home {
    margin: 10px;
  }

  &--post {
    margin: 0px 17px 0px 4px;
  }
}
```

I need to apply the parent class and the margin:10px; to the element that have the avatar--home class like that :

```html
  <div class="avatar--home"></div>
```

This is applying just the `margin: 10px;` and ignoring the parent properties

Comment: Shouldn't you use `property: inherit` for example `height:inherit` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocesser's `&` symbol copies the parent's name and doesn't copy it's properties.

However, if you want to extend your class, you can use the `@extend` mixin (for SASS) and `:extend(...)` (for LESS).

```css
/* SASS */
.avatar {
  min-width: 35px;
  max-width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  flex: 1 1 35px;
  
  &--home {
    @extend .avatar;
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

/* LESS */
.avatar {
  min-width: 35px;
  max-width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  flex: 1 1 35px;
  
  &--home:extend(.avatar) {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

Additional Links:

- [Is it possible to include the parent properties in an extended Sass class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483186/is-it-possible-to-include-the-parent-properties-in-an-extended-sass-class)
- [Does LESS have an "extend" feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464982/does-less-have-an-extend-feature)

Or you can do as @howtopythonpls suggested, just add your modifier class (since you are using BEM methodology).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just add the avatar class as well:

`<div class="avatar avatar--home"></div>`

Otherwise I think you will have to define all the properties again and set them to `inherit`, as was mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I can but i just wonder if have some way to do something like, hehe thanks man

Comment: Okey I'm pretty sure children don't inherit properties like that. Alternatively you could add them to the specific style: `.avatar, &--home, &--post { ... }`.